# How can I put this string manipulation in a loop so it continues until there's nothing left to do?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am creating a script to strip off all parts of a url other than "domain.com". I've managed to get most off, but I'm running into a problem with subfolders. Here is my code:

```
domain=$1

inp="${domain//http:'//'}"
inp="${inp//https:'//'}"
inp="${inp//www.}"
inp="${inp%/*}"
```

The problem is that for every subfolder I want to snip off, I need to create another "inp="${inp%/*}"" rule. Currently the code up there can only snip off one level, so it would work on "www.google.com/hello", but not on www.google.com/hello/there". I could add two of the rules to account for that, but I don't want to have to repeat the rule 20 times to account for all fo it.

Is there any way to throw this into a loop that would detect when it's done, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: In place of `inp="${inp%/*}"`, try: `inp="${inp%%/*}"`.

Comment: Wow that worked. It's always the smallest changes.. Thank you! Submit as an answer so I can give you credit? :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of

```
 inp="${inp%/*}"
```

Try:

```
 inp="${inp%%/*}"
```

Both of these shell substitution are examples of *suffix removal*.  The `%` form deletes the *shortest* matching suffix.  By contrast, the `%%` form removes the *longest* matching suffix.  So, if you want the first `/` and everything after it removed, use `%%/*`.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
>   **Remove matching
>   suffix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as
>   in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of
>   the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is
>   the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern
>   (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case)
>   deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is
>   applied to each positional parameter in turn,  and the expansion is
>   the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted
>   with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each  member
>   of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, I outta learn to comb through man files first.